# Android intent from vue application

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I send an android intent from a vue-web-app?

For example to start an external app to scan a barcode and return the barcode number.

I have a vue web app which runs in a browser environment and I want to start a native android app to scan a barcode. How can I send an "android intent" from this vue-web-app to achieve this? Do I need a specific plugin for example?

Comment: is there a particular reasons you need to run an external app to scan a barcode?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes. Unfortunately there is no barcode scanner for vue.js. The only existing api "vue-barcode-scanner" is no longer supported and does not run on newer android devices anymore. So I need to use a native android barcode scanner app.

Comment: yes there is - I use it - `"@zxing/library"` - works in vue2/vue3 in android and ios, even regular desktop browser

Comment: Ohhh, thank you. I will try to use this api.

Comment: If you have any issues with it, post a question. I'm more than happy to help as long as you tried :p if you do ask about it, make sure you specify if you're using vue2 or vue3

Answer (score 0):

The app you're trying to start needs to have a custom URL scheme defined in the intent filter. In that case you'll have an URI looking like this: `demoapp://scan?type=128`

When your Vue app redirects to an URI like this on an Android phone (with the app installed) it will pick up the intent and launch the app with corresponding activity started.